# SharePoint- user Contribute permission still not able to edit page?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a site at http://moss/sites/Electronics/Laptop

I have given users contribute permission on laptop site but still when they try to edit the page they are getting access denied, I have checked the permission level and all permissions are fine bt still users are not able to edit page.

I gave them read permissions on Electronics site and now they are able to edit the pages. My question is why we need to give them read permission on the top level site? What we don't want users to go to the top level site at all and want them to have an access on subsite only? Any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you understand your sites and site collections - this isn't easy because the "top level site" in a site collection is called / and child sites automatically inherit permissions if you don't specify otherwise.  Here's a diagram I made of permissions inheritance in Sharepoint 2007:
[image: Sharepoint Permission Inheritance]

[How the hell do Sharepoint Permissions Work?](http://www.dunxd.com/2010/09/how-the-hell-do-sharepoint-2007-permissions-work/)
You should also make sure you look at the permission levels you have set at the site level and the pages/document library level - make sure Contribute includes the abilities you require.

Comment: Love that graphic!

Comment: Thanks for the reply ....I checked it and as I said I want to give contribute permissions only and which i believe should be able to edit the pages....I am not inheriting the permissions at the subsite level and at the subsite I gave some users contribute permissions bt I checked in contribute permission level

Comment: Add and Customize Pages  -  Add, change, or delete HTML pages or Web Part Pages, and edit the Web site using a Windows SharePoint Services-compatible editor... is not checked do we need to check this ..bt if its unchecked by default...I am not clear on this?